# What are some essential tips for travelers to stay safe and healthy during their international trips?

Tags: international-travel

What are some essential tips for travelers to stay safe and healthy during their international trips? Please include recommendations on necessary vaccinations, precautions to take, safety measures, and any other important information to ensure a safe and healthy travel experience.

Comment: This will be different for many regions. Could you be more specific?

Comment: What have you found so far from your own research? You can find travel advice including health- and safety-related matters via a quick internet search eg [IATA](https://www.iatatravelcentre.com/) and/or sites like https://travel.state.gov/content/travel/en/international-travel/International-Travel-Country-Information-Pages.html and https://www.gov.uk/foreign-travel-advice See https://travel.stackexchange.com/help/dont-ask

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because the OP doesn’t seem to have done any research at all before posting this very broad question. Homework-related, perhaps?

Answer (score 4):

The question is too broad, but I would say:

- Check the conditions of stay in your destination and have the required paperwork (valid travel document, visas, other permits...)
- Take travel insurance and read the fine print
- Check what vaccinations are recommended for your destination, and get them
- Check if tap water is safe in your destination; if not, avoid it, as well as food washed in tap water (such as apples)
- Take precautions against weather, including (or especially) hot weather
- Try not to look like a wealthy tourist (not always possible, I know)
- Don't have sex with strangers (applies equally to paid services and casual hookups)

Comment: 6. Don't accept apparently generous offers of meals, drinks etc from local inhabitants. It can be the first move of a scam to put you on the back foot. Insist on paying, then you are not obligated. 7. Keep a small amount of cash readily available, separate from your wad.

Comment: 8. In some (low hygiene) countries, eat food that you see being prepared in front of you, or eat in busy restaurants that are popular with locals and have a quick turnover of food, i.e. is freshly cooked and not left sitting around.

Comment: 0. Check your countries foreign affairs ministry’s website for travel advice, including regions one should avoid and special precautions to take. Have the right paperwork (passport, visas..) and respect conditions of stay. Take travel insurance and read the fine print.